# How to remove "more" option from tabbar controller without delete tabs in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uitabbarcontroller

I am using tab bar controller and  i have 6 tabs when i run app at that time after 4 tab is displayed and there is more option but here i want displaying all  tabs not want to display "more" in ios 7. the code is :

```
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

    Calendar *viewController2 = [[Calendar alloc] initWithNibName:@"Calendar" bundle:nil];

    nearby *viewController3 = [[nearby alloc] initWithNibName:@"nearby" bundle:nil];
    offer *viewController4 = [[offer alloc] initWithNibName:@"offer" bundle:nil];
    social *viewController5 = [[social alloc] initWithNibName:@"social" bundle:nil];
    contact *viewController6 = [[contact alloc] initWithNibName:@"contact" bundle:nil];



    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
    UINavigationController *navController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
    UINavigationController *navController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController3];
    UINavigationController *navController3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController4];



    self.tab = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    self.tab.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController, navController1,navController2,navController3,viewController5,viewController6, nil];
    [[self.tab tabBar] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabcrop.png"]];
  self.tab.customizableViewControllers = nil;
    [[[self.tab moreNavigationController] visibleViewController] setTitle:@""];

    [self.tab.tabBar setTranslucent:YES];
    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                       [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:10.0f], UITextAttributeFont,
                                                       [UIColor yellowColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                       [UIColor redColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                                       [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, 1.0f)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                                       nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tab;
```

`

Comment: use the custom tabbar controller for it.in normal tabbar you can't do it

Comment: you cant do that. you have to use custom control. see this https://github.com/Marxon13/M13InfiniteTabBar

Answer (score 4):

According to apple's docs it is not possible: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/TabBarControllers.html

This is what it says:

> If you add more than five items to the viewControllers property, the tab bar controller automatically inserts a special view controller
>   (called the More view controller) to handle the display of the
>   additional items. The More view controller provides a custom interface
>   that lists the additional view controllers in a table, which can
>   expand to accommodate any number of view controllers. The More view
>   controller cannot be customized or selected and does not appear in any
>   of the view controller lists managed by the tab bar controller. It
>   appears automatically when it is needed and is separate from your
>   custom content.

So try custom tab bar try this:
https://github.com/Marxon13/M13InfiniteTabBar